# How to create a negative random number in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using `SQL Server 2017` and I want to know, how can I generate a random number between `0` and `-6`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do:

```
select ( 0 - floor(rand(checksum(newid())) * 7) )
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

It might works for you:

```
DECLARE @Random INT;
DECLARE @Upper INT;
DECLARE @Lower INT

---- This will create a random number between 0 and -6
SET @Lower = -6 ---- The lowest random number
SET @Upper = 0 ---- The highest random number
SELECT @Random = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0)
SELECT @Random
```

Comment: @brk No upvote ;) just kidding.. I am glad to know that, it works for you

Comment: The `-1` and the use of `ROUND` don't look right to me

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Why? ROUND function not acceptable for any other reason??

Comment: ROUND will typically leave the endpoint values under-represented, as you're mapping a smaller interval to them.  EG [-6,-5.5) -> -6, but [-5.5,-4.5) -> -5